# dependency graph resolution in Unity

Tags: .net, unity-container

Can someone shed some light on how Unity automatically does dependency graph resolution? I am not looking for the code of the algorithm, but just a simple explanation, and maybe some sort of example or analogy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity is an extensible library, so how it does its dependency resolution can be customized and changed. The default build plans however look like the following:

1. Start build up on the type requested
2. Look for the longest constructor on the type
3. Go to (1.) for each constructor parameter type
4. Create instance using resulting objects
5. Look for all public properties marked with [DependencyAttribute]
6. Go to (1.) for each property type
7. Set property values to resulting objects
8. Return created object

The build up of an object can be thought of in multiple stages. This MSDN link nicely sums up the various stages and what is performed by default at each stage: [UnityBuildStage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.objectbuilder.unitybuildstage%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a graph traversal problem. It could be depth-first, or breadth-first or who knows what else. But it's really that simple.

To resolve

```
T(X, Y)
```

First resolve `X` and `Y`. But if `X` is

```
X(A, B)
```

and Y is

```
Y(Z)
```

Resolve `A` and `B` and `Z` too. Keep going till you reach a leaf node.

Comment: So some dependencies are found in this fashion as opposed to having to declare them? For example, if we had `public class a : Ia { private IC _c }`. Then registered Ia to a, and IC to c. Then the dependency of c on IC inside of a will be automatically discovered and will not need to be declared?

Comment: No. Only dependencies on the public surface are discovered. For `IC` to be discovered, it either needs to be on the dependency constructor, or as a public property to be injected. But in general, dependencies do not need to be explicitly declared unless you need explicit control over them; they are discovered using reflection.

Comment: Sorry for not properly explaining my example. Yes, there would be a constructor in a for Ic, `public a(Ic c){ _c = c;}`.

Comment: Ah, reflection is what happens in the example to figure out the dependency? Thanks Jason :)